# Haskell foldr with function

Tags: haskell

I would like to understand how the below code of Haskell foldr is evaluated.

```
k x y = x

foldr k 1 [0..5]
```

The result is 0, but I can't understand why it is zero? I would like to think that x is 1 any the elements in the list are y. Can anyone explain it to me, please? I searched it online but couldn't found anything useful.

Comment: Hint: `foldr k 1 [0..5]` expands to `0 \`k\` foldr k 1 [1..5]`

Comment: The first function parameter receives the list elements.

Comment: I suspect you may be confusing `foldr` with `foldl`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) has some useful info about how to interpret `foldr`, including this image:

[image]

You can see how your expression expands to:

```
0 `k` (1 `k` ... (5 `k` 1)))))
```